# In how many ways can we form an n-digit number using only ... so that all digits are used

Tags: combinatorics

I have always had trouble solving this kind of problem - forming numbers involving zero.

> In how many ways can we form a 2-digit number using only 0 and 1

This one is fairly easy. The first one must be 1, thus the second one must be 0.

> In how many ways can we form a 3-digit number using only 0, 1 and 2

1. I choose the first digit in $2$ ways ($1$ or $2$)
2. Then I have $2$ numbers remaining which I distribute in $2!$ ways:
   $4$ numbers in total

> (...) 4-digit number using only 0, 1, 2 and 3

1. First digit: $3$ ways
2. Remaining digits: $3!$ ways, $18$ numbers in total

> (...) $n\le9$ -digit number using only $0,1,...,n-1%$

1. First digit: $(n-1)$ ways
2. Remaining digits: $(n-1)!$ ways
3. Total: $(n-1)(n-1)!$ numbers

Is it the right and the most appropriate way to do this or is there a different approach?

Apart from that, if the task were like this:

> In how many ways can we form a 7-digit number using only 0,1,2

1. First digit: $2$ ways
2. Every other digit: $3$ ways
3. Options where only 1 digit is used: $2$
4. Options where only 2 digits are used: $2^7$ ways
5. Total: $2\cdot3^6-2-2^7= 1328$

Could you please review this method?

Comment: The method is described systematically in these videos (about 18 mins total time): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nD2aDDK09Q&t=5s

Comment: Your answer makes sense *only in the situation that every digit must be used*.  The answer is incorrect if you are allowed to repeat digits.  For example, there is of course the two-digit number $11$ in addition to the two-digit number $10$.  If every digit must be used at least once, for the problem where you have a longer number than available digits, use inclusion-exclusion on whether or not a digit appears in the number.

Comment: @JMoravitz
Thank you! You are right, I should have included the fact that all digits must be used in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, your answer is correct for the first few examples (*after making the correction to the problem statement that every digit must be used at least once*).

To elaborate on my comment for the later problem, let $A_0$ be the set of 7-digit numbers where all digits are taken from $\{0,1,2\}$ such that there is at least one $0$.  Similarly, $A_1$ and $A_2$ have at least one $1$ and at least one $2$ respectively.

You are then tasked with counting $|A_0\cap A_1\cap A_2|$.

Letting $\Omega$ represent the set of $7$ digit numbers with digits taken from $\{0,1,2\}$ with no other restrictions, recognize that $A_0^c=\Omega\setminus A_0$ represents the set of $7$ digit numbers with *no* zeroes and digits taken from $\{0,1,2\}$.  Similarly for $A_1^c$ and $A_2^c$.  Recognize then that the total we wish to count can be rewritten as $|\Omega\setminus(A_0^c\cup A_1^c\cup A_2^c)|$ which expands via inclusion-exclusion as

$|\Omega|-|A_0^c|-|A_1^c|-|A_2^c|+|A_0^c\cap A_1^c|+|A_0^c\cap A_2^c|+|A_1^c\cap A_2^c|-|A_0^c\cap A_1^c\cap A_2^c|$

Each term of the above should be straightforward to calculate.

> $|A_0^c\cap A_2^c|$ for example is the set of seven digit numbers with no zeroes and no twos with all digits from $\{0,1,2\}$.  There is only one such number, $1111111$.  On the other hand $|A_1^c\cap A_2^c|$ is the set of seven digit numbers with no ones and no twos with all digits from $\{0,1,2\}$.  There are no such numbers since $0000000$ doesn't qualify as a seven digit number (*only as a seven digit string*).